# Showing HTML if Post is In Certain Taxonomy Term

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm using the following code to display an image based on which category a post is in on my blog. I'm trying to use this same concept under my custom post type. Instead the category is a Term in my Custom Taxonomy. How can I use the following to find the term? In_category doesn't seem to be working.

```
 <?php if (in_category('Default')) { ?>
    <img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/site/img/stars-01.png" width="100" height="21" alt="default">
    <?php } elseif (in_category('1 Star')) { ?>
    <img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/site/img/stars-01.png" width="100" height="21" alt="default">
    <?php } elseif (in_category('2 Star')) { ?>
    <img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/site/img/stars-01.png" width="100" height="21" alt="default">
    <?php } elseif (in_category('3 Star')) { ?>
    <img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/site/img/stars-01.png" width="100" height="21" alt="default">
    <?php } elseif (in_category('4 Star')) { ?>
    <img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/site/img/stars-01.png" width="100" height="21" alt="default">
    <?php } elseif (in_category('5 Star')) { ?>
    <img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/site/img/stars-01.png" width="100" height="21" alt="default">
    <?php } else { ?>
    <img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/site/img/stars-01.png" width="100" height="21" alt="default">
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [has_term()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term). Something like this:

```
<?php if( has_term('term1', 'taxonomy_name', $post) ) { ?>
    <img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/site/img/stars-01.png" width="100" height="21" alt="default">
<?php }elseif ( has_term( 'term2', 'taxonomy_name', $post) ) { ?>
    <img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/site/img/stars-01.png" width="100" height="21" alt="default">
<?php  } else { ?>
    <img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/site/img/stars-01.png" width="100" height="21" alt="default">
<?php } ?>
```

You may also want to try using shorthand if/else statements, it tends to make the code a little cleaner and easier to read in situations like like this.

Same example using shorthand:

```
<?php if( has_term('term1', 'taxonomy_name', $post) ): ?>
    <img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/site/img/stars-01.png" width="100" height="21" alt="default">
<?php elseif ( has_term( 'term2', 'taxonomy_name', $post) ) :?>
    <img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/site/img/stars-01.png" width="100" height="21" alt="default">
<?php else: ?>
    <img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/site/img/stars-01.png" width="100" height="21" alt="default">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is correct, as looking at [`in_category()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L0) code you will find that it uses `has_category()`, which itself simply reads as `return has_term( $category, 'category', $post );`.  Thus, `in_category()` specifically targets the `category` taxonomy only, but it really is little more than a shortcut for `has_term()`.

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: Contrary to what you are suggesting, one should avoid using `:` and `endif` (shorthand). The problem with this is, code editors doesn't support it, thus it makes debugging tough. Stick with old-fashioned curlies (`{}`), all editors supports it so it makes debugging a breeze

Comment: That's a great point (and one I never considered). I'm certainly not advocating using them in every situation but debugging aside (one should have more than just their editor in place for debugging at any rate), they make the code much easier to read which is handy when passing the code to another developer or revisiting it after 6 months. And if it's good enough for the [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Using_the_Loop), it's good enough for me :)